Invalid OAuth access token -- Snowflake
I generated the Public Key & assigned to the user USER1 it when I describe the user it shows the RSA_PUBLIC_KEY assigned to the user,
when I try with Private key to authenticate that is used to generate Public Key I am getting Invalid OAuth access token
Please help

How are you connecting to Snowflake? Please update your question with the command/process you are using, obviously anonymising usernames/passwords/etc

Once you generate the key pair, you map the public key with the user record on the Snowflake.
While the connection is initiated by the client, the private key has to be present in the connection string.
You confirmed that the public key is updated for the user correctly as you confirmed that same with the desc user query.
Please check that you are using the correct private key while initiating the connection from the client.
Refer to the configuration on the various client for key pairs.
enter link description here
